# Flask is not serving pages from template directory

Tags: python, flask

I have plan to convert my static bootstrap site to a web app and migrating to Flask. Only my index page is being routed correctly. I am adding other routes with the existing pages, without any luck. Screen shot below shows the app.py and directory structure i have.

> flask --version  Flask 0.12.2 Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.|
>   python --version  Python 2.7.14 ::Anaconda, Inc.

This is the folder structure

```
.
├── app.py
├── app.pyc
├── static
│   ├── css  
└── templates
    ├── about.html
    ├── blog-single.html
    ├── blog.html
    ├── contact.html
    ├── index.html
    └── store_details.html
```

This is the app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__,
    template_folder="templates")



@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/about.html")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')


@app.route("/blog.html")
def blog():
    return render_template('/blog.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is the output

```
 flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2019 15:44:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2019 15:44:49] "GET /static/js/jquery.timepicker.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2019 15:44:50] "GET /static/js/jquery.timepicker.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2019 15:44:53] "GET /about.html/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Anyone any idea what am I missing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QxuP.png)

Comment: can you provide a complete verfiable example? [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `/blog` is not the same as `/blog.html`.

Comment: @mmopu: Please [edit] your question to include the code that demonstrates your problem *in the question itself*. Don't take a screenshot of your code! Just copy/paste the code into the question directly.

Answer (score 1):

From your terminal I can see the following message:

> GET /blog.html [...] 404

Which is expected since you don't have any route with the name "/blog.html".
Instead, you have "/blog".
Any chance you have an unneeded ".html" in your path?

Comment: Even after adding the .html extension, seeing the same result. I have updated the question with code snippet. If you can recheck for any other missing bits.

Comment: I am sorry, that's not what i meant. Your code was fine, but it seems like you were trying to connect (on your browser) to /blog.html instead of just /blog.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. My redirects from the pages were to page.html, updated to the route names and working perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help :) Happy coding!